# Force specific woocommerce variation price instead of from

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce subscription product with two variations (Pay once and Pay over 12 months) in my shop/product pages the displayed price is the one of the variation (Pay over 12 months which is for ex. "From $19.9/month"). I want to show the price of the other variation (Pay once) which is the full price of the product. How can i do that?

I've tried this but it's not working

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
  $price = '';
  $price .= woocommerce_price($product->max_variation_price);
  return $price;
}
```

FYI : i have other variable products without subscription, i just want to do that only for the subscription product.

Comment: Have you tried to change places of variations in product editor page? If not, try that. In wp-admin product edit page, choose variations tab, and change their order with drag and drop. Then save and test.

Comment: I did, but the price is still the same